# Why can't I contact an external .swift document in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making an easy SpriteKit game in Swift. I made a file "EmemyAppear.swift" and put there a class and a function. That's what in this file:

```
import Foundation
class EnemyAppear {
var nowAppear = false
var waitToAppear = UInt32(0)
var appearInterval = UInt32(0)
init(nowAppear:Bool, waitToAppear:UInt32, appearInterval:UInt32) {
    self.nowAppear = nowAppear
    self.waitToAppear = waitToAppear
    self.appearInterval = appearInterval
}

func shouldRun() -> Bool {
    return self.appearInterval > self.waitToAppear
}

}
```

So then I made a dictionary in my main scene:

```
var enemyStatus:Dictionary<String,EnemyAppear> = [:]`
```

After that I'm trying to contact variables and function from EnemyAppear.swift like so:

```
func enemyRun() {
    for(enemy, enemyAppear) in self.enemyStatus {
    var thisPet = self.childNodeWithName(enemy)!
        if enemyStatus.shouldRun() {
            enemyStatus.waitToAppear = random()
            enemyStatus.appearInterval = 0
            enemyStatus.nowAppear = true
        }
    }
}
```

But Xcode tells me for example that `Dictionary <String, EnemyAppear> doesn't have a member named 'shouldRun'`
But it does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you want to access enemyAppear, but access enemyStatus instead (which is, indeed, a dictionary)

Comment: Oh my god, how dumb am I! Thank you guys, so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if enemyStatus.shouldRun()
```

enemyStatus is a Dictionary, not an EnemyAppear, then it doesn't have a member named 'shouldRun'. It should be

```
if enemyAppear.shouldRun()
```